# Add extra fields to User Profile view in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm using `Django 2.x` and `Django REST Framework` and `Django REST Auth`

By default, Django REST Auth provides an endpoint for Profile Details which returns details of authenticated user from the `User` model.

The default view provides fields

```
fields = ('pk', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

and the endpoint is `/api/user/`

I want to add more fields to the serializer as I'm using a custom User model and have more fields added to it.

**Do I need to create a Custom view and redefine the serializer class or I can extend the default provided view and serializer to add extra fields?**

Comment: What do you mean by the 'default view'? Which view class provided by DRF does that? If you have a custom User model, you should use `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()` to get the `User` model (which is your custom model) and your view can then access all your `User` model's fields.

Comment: Its `UserDetailsView` from `rest_auth/views`. Updated question with correct refrence.

Comment: That's not part of DRF. You apparently are using django-rest-auth which is an additional package on top of DRF.

Comment: I'm sure rest-auth is a good Django citizen and uses `get_user_model()` and not `django.contrib.auth.models.User`, so the view is showing your custom `User` model. Just subclass it to add your own `serializer_class` with the fields you want. Check the rest_auth source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [docs](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#configuration) you'll set that there is a configuration option for custom serializers. You can define your custom `serializers` for each endpoint without overriding `urls` and `views` by adding `REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS` dictionary in your django settings.

Example:

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER': 'path.to.custom.serializer' 
}
```